# Jack McDevitt book where a toy-like spaceship turns out to be real for a small butterfly-like spacefaring race

Tags: story-identification, novel, jack-mcdevitt

I am looking for a particular Jack McDevitt novel, I believe set in the *Alex Benedict* series. It may have been a subplot or the main plot, but they find a toy-like spaceship, only to uncover near the end that it is actually a real spacecraft, used by a small butterfly-like spacefaring race.

I have looked at all my Jack McDevitt *Academy* and *Alex Benedict* series books, of which I have all except *Cauldron*, and I don't think it is *Cauldron*.

Comment: See OP confirmation comment below.

Answer (score 10):

I don't recall this book, but some searching suggests that this is probably [*Infinity Beach*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?20845).  In a snippet from a review of *Infinity Beach* in [*The New York Review of Science Fiction*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=3wxhAAAAMAAJ&dq=jack+mcdevitt+butterfly&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22resembling+a+butterfly%22) I found this quote:

> Admirably, McDevitt's alien is truly alien; a life form resembling a butterfly and many times smaller than humans

Comment: It might be worth adding that this is also published under the name Slow Lightning in (at least) the UK.

Comment: Thank you much!

Comment: @MaribelPerez You should accept this answer (by clicking the checkmark under the voting arrows in the upper left) so that future searchers know that this question has been answered.